# localhost shows ip 127 instead of 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, xampp, ip-address

Well, I tried to get the visitor's ip & got an interesting issue.
When I tried to return visitor's ip with simple SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], the returned ip I got is 127.0.0.1. But when I tried it with some checks. I got only 127. Below here is the code.

I am using php 5.5.9 on XAMPP local server

```
<?php 

$http_client_ip = $_SERVER['http_client_ip'];
$http_forwareded_x_for= $_SERVER['http_forwareded_x_for'];
$http_remoteAdd= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$ip_address;
echo $http_remoteAdd.'<br>';


if(!empty($http_client_ip)){
    $ip_address=$http_client_ip;
    echo "Its not empyt";
} else if (!empty($http_forwareded_x_for)) {
    echo "Its not emply";
    $ip_address=$http_forwareded_x_for;
} else  {
    $ip_address =$http_remoteAdd;
    echo 'its working. <br>';
}

echo 'Your ip address is: '+ $ip_address;

 ?>
```

Comment: I have also tried it on server. It shows there something like:119.154.247.148
its working. 
119.154

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, your PHP code is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't `http_forwareded_x_for` be `http_forwarded_x_for`?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
echo 'Your ip address is: '+ $ip_address;
```

turns `$ip_address` into a number, specifically `127.0`. You want to concatenate, not add:

```
echo 'Your ip address is: ' . $ip_address;
```